# Is phrase "getting to speak to" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

> I loved everything about your company from making computers to repairing them to shipping them and **getting to speak to** all the different kinds of people from around the world.

I'm more concerned about the phrase "getting to speak to"?

And is this sentence grammatically correct? (overall)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with *getting to speak to*.

It functions in a way similar to *being able to speak to* and *having the opportunity to speak to*.

You could also just say *and speaking to*, but the added *getting to* implies gratitude for them taking some time to talk with you.